# i can't add to db table and the error Errors Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path AND Syntax error in SQL statement

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I'm trying to make an add service to my loan table that has a ManytoOne relation with the table User in a spring boot project this is the error

```
Hibernate: select null,u1_0.date_of_birth,u1_0.adress,u1_0.email,u1_0.firstname,u1_0.lastname,u1_0.pwd,u1_0.region,u1_0.role,u1_0.status,u1_0.work from user u1_0 where u1_0.id=?
Hibernate: insert into loan (start,amount,bankstat,cin,diploma,duration,pack_id,possession,state,user_id,work) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
2024-03-23T22:29:46.992+01:00 ERROR 5268 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : tn.esprit.insurance.entities.Loan.user -> tn.esprit.insurance.entities.User] with root cause
```

this is the entity Loan

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private float amount;
    private int duration;
    private LocalDate Start;
    private String cin;
    private String possession;
    private String diploma;
    private String work;
    private String bankstat;
    private String state;
    @ManyToOne
    Pack pack;
    @ManyToOne
    User user;
```

i was expecting code 200 with description OK but i got 500